# Determine if characters in a string are all of a specific character set

Tags: java, character-encoding

I need to be able to take a string in Java and determine whether or not all of the characters contained within it are in a specified character set (e.g. ISO-8859-1).  I've looked around quite a bit for a simple way to do this (including playing around with a `CharsetDecoder`), but have yet to be able to find something.

What is the best way to take a string and determine if all the characters are within a given character set?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Class [CharsetEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html) in package [java.nio.charset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/package-summary.html) offer a method [canEncode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html#canEncode%28char%29) to test if a specific character is supported.

[Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/614418/michael) basically did something like this:

[`Charset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html).[`forName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29)( [`CharEncoding.ISO_8859_1`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/CharEncoding.html#ISO_8859_1) ).[`newEncoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#newEncoder%28%29)().[`canEncode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html#canEncode%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)("string")

Note that `CharEncoding.ISO_8859_1` rely on [Apache commons](http://commons.apache.org/) and may be replaced by "ISO_8859_1".

Comment: Excellent! That seems to do exactly what I want and is extremely clean and simple. Now I feel silly for asking after spending all this time looking at the opposite class (`CharsetDecoder`).  Thanks!

Comment: Just for reference for anyone I basically did something like this: `Charset.forName(CharEncoding.ISO_8859_1).newEncoder().canEncode("string")`

Comment: I know this post is old, but it was the first result in my search.  For those who want to determine if a string is encoded in one of the IBM EBCDIC character sets, like IBM-1047, use "Cp1047".  For IBM-737 use "Cp737.

Reference Java 7 documentation:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html

Answer (score 2):

I think that the easiest way will be to have a table of which Unicode characters can be represented in the target character set encoding and then testing each character in the string. For the ISO-8859 family, the table can usually be represented by one or a few ranges of Unicode characters, making the test relatively easy. It's a lot of hand work, but needs to be done only once.

**EDIT:** or use [Aubin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13144332/535871) if the charset is supported in your Java implementation. :)

Comment: @Aubin - Cheers. Of course, your solution only works if the Java implementation supports the target [`CharSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html). (No problem for ISO-8859-1 and the other standard charsets, but other ISO-8859 encodings are usually not supported.)