# Check if a String contains characters which aren't UTF-8 encoded in Java

Tags: java, utf-8

Before any claim, I've checked out:
[Determine if characters in a string are all of a specific character set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13144250/determine-if-characters-in-a-string-are-all-of-a-specific-character-set)

**...and tried the selected answer (with UTF-8):**
`StandardCharsets.UTF_8.newEncoder().canEncode(input);`

With my input which is a String

> I also tried `CharsetDecoder` without any valuable result (it always gets acknowledged as valid)

Comment: Check this link, it might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622226/check-if-a-string-is-valid-utf-8-encoded-in-java

Comment: As far as I know, the expression `StandardCharsets.UTF_8.newEncoder().canEncode(input);` is equivalent to `true` (i.e. any java `String` can be encoded in UTF-8)

Comment: Do you have examples of input Strings?

Comment: @Bentaye yes I tried with this one ``

Comment: @Eran Could be, I have seen some examples where a ' UnsupportedEncodingException` may be thrown

Comment: @Alan which encoding was used in those examples, and which characters failed to be encoded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Java `String` is in UTF-16 format:

> A String represents a string in the **UTF-16 format** in which supplementary characters are represented by surrogate pairs (see the section Unicode Character Representations in the Character class for more information). Index values refer to char code units, so a supplementary character uses two positions in a String.

[UTF-16 is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16):

> UTF-16 (16-bit Unicode Transformation Format) is a character encoding **capable of encoding all 1,112,064 valid code points of Unicode**.

[UTF-8 is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8):

> UTF-8 is a variable width character encoding **capable of encoding all 1,112,064 valid code points in Unicode** using one to four 8-bit bytes.

It follows that every character that can appear in a java `String` can be encoded in `UTF-8`.

Therefore

```
StandardCharsets.UTF_8.newEncoder().canEncode(input);
```

should always return true.

Comment: Corollary, answering the title question, no String in Java is UTF-8 encoded.