# How can I check if a charset of a string is the same as the charset of the device's set language

Tags: java, android

I want to detect if a string contains characters that are not in the device's language characters

Is it possible?

Some of my app users write in arabic, the rest write in english. I need to translate text only when the text is in arabic and the user's device is in english or the other way around

Comment: What do you mean by "the device's language"?

Comment: It sounds like this is not about charsets, but rather you are interested in whether a String contains characters from a particular script.  You can do this with something like `string.matches(".*\\p{IsArabic}.*")`.

Comment: @VGR what is IsArabic?

Comment: It is equivalent to `\\p{script=Arabic}` (which is also a valid regex).  It matches a single character whose Unicode script designation is the [Arabic script](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.UnicodeScript.html#ARABIC).  The "Unicode Support" section of [the javadoc for java.util.regex.Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) has a full description of permitted \\p{…} expressions.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the device language by

```
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();
```

And then do a checking on the input string to see if any character in the string is in the range between
`\u0600` and `\u06FF` (Arabic charset in Unicode), then it should do the trick

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11309694/1831275) is the answer of how to check if the string is in a specific charset

```
public boolean isEncoded(String text){
    Charset charset = Charset.forName("US-ASCII");
    String checked=new String(text.getBytes(charset),charset);
    return !checked.equals(text);
}
```

Comment: How do I check the range?

Comment: I think your answer almost does what I need. except it always returns true even if the mobile's current language is in arabic. I need to set the Charset.forName dynamically to whatever the name is for the mobiles language. do you know how can that be obtained?

Comment: Charset ysb = Charset.defaultCharset();
      Charset charset = Charset.forName(ysb.displayName());  always returns false

Comment: In this case I think there's nothing more to do than simply doing a loop inside specific range of Unicode to see if there's a character inside that range.